# Fazer pop-up abrir após um tempo

Tags: javascript

Tenho um pop-up e gostaria que ele abrisse depois que o usuário já está um tempo em determinado link.

Meu JS está assim:

```
 if($('.popup-banner').length > 0) {
    (window.location.href === '/')
    $('.popup-banner .fechar, .popup-banner .link-fechar, .popup-overlay').click(function() {
        $('.popup-overlay, .popup-banner').fadeOut(400);
    });
}
```

Onde coloco o *delay*?

Comment: Utilize `setTimeout( function() { /* Seu código */ }, delayEmMilissegundos);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` e mostre a *popup* com `.fadeIn()`, desta forma:

```
if($('.popup-banner').length > 0) {
    (window.location.href === '/')

    setTimeout(function(){
       $(".popup-banner").fadeIn();
    }, 3000); // 3000 = 3 segundos

    $('.popup-banner .fechar, .popup-banner .link-fechar, .popup-overlay').click(function() {
        $('.popup-overlay, .popup-banner').fadeOut(400);
    });
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
if($('.popup-banner').length > 0) {
    (window.location.href === '/')
    
    setTimeout(function(){
       $(".popup-banner").fadeIn();
    }, 3000); // 3000 = 3 segundos
    
    $('.popup-banner .fechar, .popup-banner .link-fechar, .popup-overlay').click(function() {
        $('.popup-overlay, .popup-banner').fadeOut(400);
    });
}
```

```css
.popup-banner{
   display: none;
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Aguarde 3 segundos...
<div class="popup-banner">
   pop up
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mantive apenas o que fará o elemento abrir:

```
setTimeout( function() {
   $('.popup-overlay, .popup-banner').fadeOut(400);
},3000)
```

Isso faz com que a função do click deixe de funcionar, já que a ideia é abrir automático.

Se quiser manter o click, mantenha seu código já existente (que trata apenas o click) e adicione este novo, que fará a mesma coisa, porém considerando APENAS o tempo.

Note que o 3000 é o tempo em milissegundos.